# Word warping multiple lines algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that there is a list of words; each word i has a length w[i]. I am asked to find a way to distribute those words on one or more lines so that

a) The total length of words on any line does not exceed a given value L, and

b) If S[j] is the remaining space on line j after putting the words on it, and K = max(S[j]), then K must be minimum of all ways to distribute the words.

Assume that there is no space between words on a line, and w[i] <= L.

For example, if w = {a, ab, abc, 123z} and L = 5, then we have

```
a123z
ababc
```

where S[j] = 0 and K = 0.

If w = {a, ab, abc, 123z} and L = 4, then we have

```
aab
abc
123z
```

where S[1] = 1, S[2] = 1, S[3] = 0, and K = 1.

Constraints: the maximum number of words is 4000 and L <= 70.

I completely have no idea for this problem except brute force. It is not dynamic programming to me either. I appreciate for any help.

EDIT: The words do not have to be in the order they appear in the list.

Comment: This is similar (but not quite the same) as the "cutting stock problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: It's the *bin packing problem* which is NP-hard.

Comment: Ah, I see. I spent a lot of time thinking about the problem without knowing it's an NP-hard problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not bin-packing if the words must appear in the order that they're given. Which makes sense, since this is a "word wrapping multiple lines algorithm." Also the small example given in the question does not rearrange the words. If the words must appear in the same order, it's not NP-hard, and in fact it's linear -- as described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for a confusion. The words do not have to be in the same order they appear. I will edit the question. Thank you very much for your answer.